# Get event on Coming back to current page, Ionic navigation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am showing some list from api in Page-A, from page-A, I navigate to Page-B, and fill some form and submit, after submission I moved back to Page-A. Now I need to refresh the list in Page-A.

How can i know that I have moved back from Page-B -> Page-A.

I am using Ionic-5.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ionic Life Cycle Hooks:

> `ionViewWillEnter` Fired when the component routing to is about to animate into view.

> `ionViewWillLeave` Fired when the component routing from is about to animate.

> `ionViewDidLeave` Fired when the component routing to has finished animating.

> `ionViewDidEnter` Fired when the component routing to> has finished animating.

For More Info: [Life Cycle Hooks Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#ionic-page-events)

Comment: lifecycle view not work when coming back from navigation, as the component is already in the stack.

Comment: can you share your routing code so i can have a look at it. also share your current life cyle code.

Comment: this.router.navigateByUrl('call-add');   this is how i am going to other route/page.

Answer (score 1):

**SERVICE booleanService**

```
comingFromPageB: boolean;
```

**PAGE B**

```
constructor(private booleanService: BooleanService){}

ionViewWillLeave(){
this.booleanService.comingFromPageB = true;
}
```

**PAGE A**

```
constructor(private booleanService: BooleanService){}

ionViewWillEnter(){
  if(this.booleanService.comingFromPageB){
    - Do your stuff here (delete form...)
     - Reset boolean : this.booleanService.comingFromPageB = false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve these things by using events and subscribe concept. Like as below

Step 1: Create one service(provider) with apphelper name

Step 2: run this npm i rxjs command

Step 3: import below things in apphelper.service.ts and

```
    import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

    // Events
  subscribe(topic: string, observer: (_: any) => void): Subscription {
    if (!this.channels[topic]) {
      this.channels[topic] = new Subject<any>();
    }
    return this.channels[topic].subscribe(observer);
  }

  publish(topic: string, data?: any): void {
    const subject = this.channels[topic];
    if (!subject) {
      // Or you can create a new subject for future subscribers
      return;
    }
    subject.next(data);
  }

  destroy(topic: string): null {
    const subject = this.channels[topic];
    if (!subject) {
      return;
    }
    subject.complete();
    delete this.channels[topic];
  }
```

Now import service on page A and page B. After that add click event in back button and fire publish the event as below on page B:

```
 this.appHelper.publish("RELOAD_DATA");
```

And on page A subscribe event in the constructor as below:

```
this.appHelper.subscribe("RELOAD_DATA", (data: any) => {
// call the function as per your requirement
    });
```

Comment: yes, i have already integrated NGXS for state management, i am trying to use that,  just curious if any out of the box provided by Ionic.